# How many cycles does a cache read of an invalid block takes with cache coherence?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, x86-64, multicore

For [MESI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) cache coherence, how many cycles it would take If a processor has an invalid cache block, but another processor has that cache block. How long it would take for the processor that has that cache block to transfer it to the reading processor? Would it happen just in one cycle or would it take more? Note that here we are not going down to the lower cache memory as the processor that has that cache block could directly send it to the reading processor.

Comment: You can hardly get more implementation defined than that. Heck MESI doesn't even make any guarantees that going from I->S means that you get the data from another processor, it'd be just as valid to load it from memory.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer per se but considering that an x86 cache block is 64 bytes long the actual transfer might require 8 cycles on a 64-bit wide (internal cache) data bus or 4 on a 128-bit bus. Then there is the time required for one cache to determine that it actually has pertinent data and to initiate the transfer.

Based on this conjecture you are looking at 8+x or 4+x cycles.

Comment: Also note that it could be "bus cycles" and not "CPU cycles" - e.g. depending on the speed of a quick-path link.

Comment: Most on-chip caches run at the same clock frequency as the CPU core(s). Going off-chip is, of course, slower.